# How to fire a get request as per the user input using Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I will get output of a get request as follows

```
[u'Mango', u'Banana', u'Apple', u'Grapes']
```

And i will be asking user to select one of the fruit

```
fruit_name = raw_input("Enter fruit name from the above list :")
```

Once i get the input from user i wanted fire request as per the user input as below...

If fruit_name is Mango

execute below get request

```
http://12.345.67.891:8000/api/datasources/proxy/1/query?db=UK_GHS&q=SELECT%20sum(%22count%22)%20FROM%20%22gatling%22%20WHERE%20%22status%22%20%3D%20%27ok%27%20AND%20%22simulation%22%20%3D~%20%2Fsoak-test*%2F%20AND%20time%20%3E%201544491800000ms%20and%20time%20%3C%201544495400000ms%20GROUP%20BY%20%22script%22&epoch=ms
```

If fruit_name is Banana

```
http://12.345.67.891:8000/api/datasources/proxy/1/query?db=UK_GHS&q=SELECT%20sum(%22count%22)%20FROM%20%22gatling%22%20WHERE%20%22status%22%20%3D%20%27ok%27%20AND%20%22simulation%22%20%3D~%20%2Fspike-test*%2F%20AND%20time%20%3E%201544491800000ms%20and%20time%20%3C%201544495400000ms%20GROUP%20BY%20%22script%22&epoch=ms
```

If fruit_name is Apple

```
http://12.345.67.891:8000/api/datasources/proxy/1/query?db=UK_GHS&q=SELECT%20sum(%22count%22)%20FROM%20%22gatling%22%20WHERE%20%22status%22%20%3D%20%27ok%27%20AND%20%22simulation%22%20%3D~%20%2Fload-test*%2F%20AND%20time%20%3E%201544491800000ms%20and%20time%20%3C%201544495400000ms%20GROUP%20BY%20%22script%22&epoch=ms
```

Can someone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding onto @jezrael's answer, you can do something like this:

```
L = [u'Mango', u'Banana', u'Apple', u'Grapes']

fruit_name = raw_input("Enter fruit name from the above list :")
url_dict = {'Mango': 'http://12.345.67.891:8000/api/datasources/proxy/1/query',
            'Banana': 'http://10.111.21.314:8000/api/datasources/proxy/1/query',
            'Apple': 'http://15.161.71.819:8000/api/datasources/proxy/1/query',
            'Grapes': 'http://20.212.22.324:8000/api/datasources/proxy/1/query'}
print url_dict.get(fruit_name, 'No URL configured')
```

Answer (score 2):

If different values per list better is create dictionary for lookup with `get` method for return value if no match:

```
d = {'Mango': 'http://12.345.67.891:8000/api/datasources/proxy/1/query?db=UK_GHS&q=SELECT%20sum(%22count%22)%20FROM%20%22gatling%22%20WHERE%20%22status%22%20%3D%20%27ok%27%20AND%20%22simulation%22%20%3D~%20%2Fsoak-test*%2F%20AND%20time%20%3E%201544491800000ms%20and%20time%20%3C%201544495400000ms%20GROUP%20BY%20%22script%22&epoch=ms',
     'Banana':'http://12.345.67.891:8000/api/datasources/proxy/1/query?db=UK_GHS&q=SELECT%20sum(%22count%22)%20FROM%20%22gatling%22%20WHERE%20%22status%22%20%3D%20%27ok%27%20AND%20%22simulation%22%20%3D~%20%2Fspike-test*%2F%20AND%20time%20%3E%201544491800000ms%20and%20time%20%3C%201544495400000ms%20GROUP%20BY%20%22script%22&epoch=ms',
     'Apple':'http://12.345.67.891:8000/api/datasources/proxy/1/query?db=UK_GHS&q=SELECT%20sum(%22count%22)%20FROM%20%22gatling%22%20WHERE%20%22status%22%20%3D%20%27ok%27%20AND%20%22simulation%22%20%3D~%20%2Fload-test*%2F%20AND%20time%20%3E%201544491800000ms%20and%20time%20%3C%201544495400000ms%20GROUP%20BY%20%22script%22&epoch=ms'}
```

---

```
fruit_name = raw_input("Enter fruit name from the above list :")

out = d.get(fruit_name, 'No value in list')
print out
```

---

```
Enter fruit name from the above list :Banana
http://10.111.21.314:8000/api/datasources/proxy/1/query
```

---

```
Enter fruit name from the above list :test
No value in list
```

Comment: Python 2 solution i can implement but for loop url is same for all user inputs with just replacing the user input after DB. Actually URL will completely changes as per the input in that case i will not be able to use the same link with DB parameter change in the for loop.

Comment: @SwethaGorantla - Can you be more specific? If url are changed,via  what is logic behind it? How is possible map user input to some url, if different? Can you explian more, the best  via [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54721050/edit) with your code?

Comment: Edited the code. Why i need is URL is completely different as per the fruit_name.

Comment: Edited the code with complete URL for clear information. If user input is apple we just cannot replace apple the URL. We have send different simulation name in the request. Like that simulation name is different for different user inputs.

Comment: @SwethaGorantla - So in url is information `Banana`, `Mango` ? So dictionary with `get` cannot be used?

Comment: How to send session attributes in the get request? s = requests.Session(). In the previous step i used session as below..

    dashboard = 'http://12.345.67.891:8000/api/search?query=&starred=false'
    dashboardr = s.get(dashboard)
    response_str = dashboardr.content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188510/discussion-between-jezrael-and-swetha-gorantla).